# Java converting Jar project to War Project

Tags: java, tomcat

I've built a java program that logs into a game server and asks the user for an input ID and then sends a packer to the game server and parses and prints out the reply.

I need to convert this into an API that will be run on Tomcat I assume? I've installed Tomcat on my server but I am not sure what to do now and what the correct way to convert this would be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar things in the past.  Mainly turn regular applications into web applications.  Or more simply put, wrapping an application inside a Servlet web application so it can be controlled via an HTTP API.

By the way there are multiple ways to do this.  Many in fact.  This is just one way.  Servlets is a Java interface that allows developers to quickly create a server, mainly an HTTP server, though its not limited to just that.  Tomcat is a Servlet container.  That means you can create a Servlet, then register it to the Servlet container, either using a special file called a web.xml or annotations.  In the example below I use the WebServlet annotation to register my Servlet with Tomcat.  Once registered, Tomcat will send any requests destined to the your application (the name of the WAR file) and to the specific Servlet (the registered urlPatterns, see example below).  So if your WAR file is named "MyWebServer", and your Servlet has registered the urlPattern "getSomething", then any requests to the Tomcat with the URL MyWebServer/getSomething, will be directed to your Servelet's doGet or doPost command.  If you do a simple browser request (or curl on Linux) with no msg body, then by default its a HTTP GET request.  Stick with GET requests for now until you get the hang of it.

A couple of things you will need.

1)  Know how to package a Java application into a WAR file.  The WAR file would then just go to into Tomcat's webapp folder.  When Tomcat starts up it will unzip the WAR files in that directory and host the web application implemented in that WAR file.  Please read up on WAR files.  The easiest way to do it is to use your IDE, I prefer Netbeans, and click on new project.  In Netbeans you can select new Maven->Web Application project -or- Java->Web Application.  It will set up the directory structure.

2)  You will need a Servlet.  Create a Servet, please read up on it.  Once again your IDE will make things easy for you.  In Servlet 3.x you can configure your Servlet using annotations.  Your Servlet will actually be a HttpServet.  Here is a simple example, you will have to look up the various components (like HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse) to get the full blown details.  Stackoverflow has a treasure trove of information on how those two work.

```
@WebServlet(name = "MyWebServer", urlPatterns = {"/getSomething", "/postSomething"}, loadOnStartup = 1)
public class MyWebServer extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
                //Get the input to your web service from the HttpServletRequest.
                String someParam = request.getParameter("someParamName");

                //process your request
                String output = yourExistingClass.processSomething(someParam);

                //set the response
                try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
                    out.println(output);
                }               
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //public functions
    @Override
    public void init() {
        //put any code you want executed when the application comes up in here.
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        //put any code you want executed when the application comes down in here.   
    }
}
```

3)  You will need to include your JAR in your application.  Once again your IDE can help you add your JAR to your project.  Your JAR, and any other dependency JAR's will get packaged inside your WAR, specifically inside the WEB-INF/lib  folder.

I hope this helps get you started.